# Visual Studio 2010 crashes on view properties

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Somehow my Properties window has become detached. When I view properties of any item in the Solution Explorer, it pops up but then I get a message that Visual Studio has stopped unexpectedly.

I've gone through my solution and deleted all .user and .suo files, but it still happens. I've also tried the reset layout option and no luck.

There must be a docking information file somewhere that I could delete or edit.

How can this be solved?

Comment: "Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are usually stored in a .vssettings file.  So you could find that and delete/rename it.

Try running this in the command line:

> devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Comment: Deleting the .vssettings file did not fix the problem, but running the commandline fix did - thanks!